# At what distance does a man, whose height is 2m subtend an angle of 10' ?

Tags: geometry

I tried using the angle in radian = length of arc/radius of circle and got the answer as 974.0286 m. But the answer given in the answer's section is 687.5m. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I did the same thing and got $687.5$ metres.  I don't think anyone will be able to say what you did wrong unless you give more details of what you actually did.

Comment: I let the distance be 'r'. Converted the angle to radians and got 3.141/1080 rads. Then I used the above theorem.

Comment: Please don't delete your question when someone has gone to the effort of providing you an answer.

Comment: @robjohn Thanks. In fairness, it looked like my post happened at about the same time the OP deleted the question, so s/he may have not been aware of it.

Comment: @dxiv: Good point. It was deleted just one second after your answer was posted. I was jaded by having dealt with other, less innocent situations where the question was deleted after an answer was posted. Thanks!

Comment: It would help to know how you got the answer $974.0286\text{m}$ in order to answer the question "What am I doing wrong?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since no work was shown, it is hard to answer the question "What am I doing wrong?" However, providing a possible solution may give a clue.

$10'=\frac\pi{1080}$ is a small enough angle that
$$
\frac{\tan\left(\frac\pi{1080}\right)}{\frac\pi{1080}}=1.00000282
$$
So we need only compute
$$
\frac{2\text{m}}{\frac\pi{1080}}=687.55\text{m}
$$
and not have to worry about tangents, which is good since we might need $2\tan\left(\frac\pi{2160}\right)$ or $\tan\left(\frac\pi{1080}\right)$ depending on whether we are in line with the middle of the person or in line with the top of their head (and we are not given that information).

Answer (score 1):

Going by the notation, $10'$ is the arc measure in [minutes of an arc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minute_and_second_of_arc).

Then the angle in radians is $\alpha = 10' = \frac{\pi}{1080}$ and the [distance is](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=cot(pi+%2F+(2+%2A+1080))) $\frac{1}{2} \cdot 2\,\text{m} \cdot \cot(\alpha / 2) = 687.548... \,\text{m}\;$.

Answer (score 0):

Since angle sub. is very small therefore the height of the mab can be considered as the arc lenght. 
i.e. L = 2 m 
Angle  α = 10'=10/60 degree
Since, L/R =α
therefore R=2x6x180x7/22=687.26 cm